# How to track intermediate scalars with keras/tensorflow that depend on the label

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a model that takes two float lists as input, computes an embedding for each input, concatenates the embeddings together, then tries to predict two different labels.

What I would like to do is, during training in my tensorboard I'd like to monitor the euclidean distance between the embeddings, but separated by positive and negative labels.

Some example code:

```
input_features = {'feat1': tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=[2], dtype=tf.float32, default_value=None),
                  'feat2': tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=[2], dtype=tf.float32, default_value=None)}
inputs = {name: tf.keras.Input(
      shape=(feature.shape[-1]), name=name) for name, feature in input_features.items()
  }

embedding_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4)
feat1_embedded = embedding_layer(inputs['feat1'])
feat2_embedded = embedding_layer(inputs['feat2'])

distance = tf.norm(
  feat2_embedded - feat1_embedded, ord='euclidean', axis=1, keepdims=None, name=None
)
distance = tf.keras.backend.print_tensor(distance, f"distance: ", summarize=-1)

concatenated_features = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([feat1_embedded, feat2_embedded], axis=-1)
prediction1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", name="prediction1")(concatenated_features)
prediction2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", name="prediction2")(concatenated_features)

outputs = {'my_label1': prediction1,
           'my_label2': prediction2,
           'distance': distance}
metrics = {'my_label1': ["accuracy"],
           'my_label2': ["accuracy"],}
losses = {'my_label1': tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
          'my_label2': tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()}

model = tf.keras.Model(
    inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='test_model'
)
model.summary()

model.compile(
    loss=losses,
    metrics=metrics,
)

X_test = {'feat1': np.array([[.1, .1],
                             [.2, .2],
                             [.3, .3]]),
          'feat2': np.array([[.2, .2],
                             [.4, .4],
                             [.8, .8]]),}
y_test = {'my_label1': np.array([[1],
                                [0],
                                [1]]),
          'my_label2': np.array([[0],
                                [1],
                                [1]]),
          }
print(model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0, return_dict=True))
```

So at this point the "distance" tensor has the euclidean distance between the feature embeddings for each example in a batch. I want to mask this value and see it for positive and negative examples separately according to "my_label1", in my tensorboard, averaged over the epoch.

How can I accomplish this? I can't figure out what combination of Metrics, Callbacks, or tf.summary.scalar I need to use.